# Is there a Google API we can use to get user's Google Workspace Organization Information?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-people-api

We're adding Google as an identity provider to our application and we're hoping to get information about the user's organization to control access to resources.

I've tried the People's API `https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=organizations` so far but it does not return my organization details even though I'm part of an organization.

```
# Response

{
    "resourceName": "people/my_id",
    "etag": "%tag"
}
```

From what I've read Google+ API has been deprecated as well so I'm not sure if there's still an API that can accomplish this.

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by organization details?

Comment: The organization name would be enough for us but would be interesting to see if there is other information we can use.

Comment: hmm okay let me dig a little it should be there someplace.  To be clear we are talking about workspace origination, not just something the user added under company right.

Comment: Have you tried using the [Resource: members](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/members) or maybe the [Resource: users](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users) from the Directory API?

Comment: I've seen this as well @Kessy but I don't think it's the API that I'm looking for. This API would give me access to the entire workspace directory whereas the goal is to get the org information of the currently logged-in user only.

Comment: Are your users part of the organization you are in? Can you clarify your intended use?

Comment: It will be a typical login using Google implementation which utilizes Google's OAuth service. Users can be from different organizations. When they signed in to the app, the users will have access to resources activated for their organization. An individual user can activate resources for their organization which will be seen by other users on the same organization.

Comment: Have you checked on the OAuth Documentation? This may be what you are looking for: [Getting profile information](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/people)

Comment: I did but it only provides very limited information. Mainly id, first name, last name, full name, image URL, and email.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that to recover this information from customers outside your organization is not possible.

You can create a Feature Request on Google's Issue Tracker to ask for this feature. This is the link for the Admin SDK template:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191635&template=824102